# It is possible to create a normal distribution in netlogo with maximum and minimum values?

Tags: netlogo

Suppose I have X patches, and patches have a patch variable call "patch-quality", with values between 0 and 1. I want to generate a random number between 0 and 1 for that variable following a normal distribution.

When you set up a normal distribution in NetLogo, you need a mean and a standard deviation:

```
random-normal mean standard-deviation
```

The mean for my normal distribution is 0.5 (mean of 0 and 1), but is there a way to choose an standard deviation so NetLogo wouldn't generate patches with patch-quality below 0 and above 1?

In summary, what I want is a normal distribution where the minimum value of patch-quality is 0, maximum is 1, and mean is 0.5.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a real problem in ABMs, such that we address it [in our book (Sect. 15.3.2)](https://www.railsback-grimm-abm-book.com). Even though values above and below 3 standard deviations are rare... we often draw many many thousands of values so they **will** occur.

The solution in the previous answer works, and I used it for many years. Just be aware that now your values will not really follow a  normal distributions.

I also often use a triangular distribution instead. All values drawn from a triangular distribution are within a specified range, and values near the center are more likely. It has the additional advantage that the most-likely value (the mode) does not have to be at the center of the range.

Here is the triangular distribution procedure I use (having stolen the algorithm from Wikipedia):

```
to-report random-triangular [a-min a-mode a-max]
  ; Return a random value from a triangular distribution
  ; Method from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution#Generating_Triangular-distributed_random_variates
  ; Obtained 2015-11-27

  if (a-min > a-mode) or (a-mode > a-max) or (a-min >= a-max)
   [ error (word "Random-triangular received illegal parameters (min, mode, max): " a-min " " a-mode " " a-max) ]

  let a-rand random-float 1.0
  let F (a-mode - a-min) / (a-max - a-min)

  ifelse a-rand < F
  [ report a-min + sqrt (a-rand * (a-max - a-min) * (a-mode - a-min)) ]
  [ report a-max - sqrt ((1 - a-rand) * (a-max - a-min) * (a-max - a-mode)) ]

end
```

Steve Railsback

Comment: Thanks Railsback!. The solution Jumboman offers is also useful and would work well in practice. I think that this triangular distribution is going to solve this problem in a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2):

that signature never exists for normal distribution functions, because it's not how they are conceptually used. However, values more than 3 times the standard deviation above or below the average rarely happen. By setting your mean to 0.5 and your standard devation to +- 0.15, numbers above 1 or below 0 shouldn't occur much. If you want to enfore this, you could simply add another line of code:

```
ask patches with [number < 0] [set number 0]
```

and ditto for the >1 case. this should be close to what you're asking.

Comment: This is a nice idea, thank you very much Jumboman!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to these two answers that a beta distribution with high alpha and beta values also approaches a normal distribution ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Normal_approximation_to_the_Beta_distribution)), while being restricted to [0,1]. It is already available in Netlogo through the rngs extension.

The following code let's you quickly visualise the probability distributions of different alpha and beta values:

```
extensions [rngs] 

to plotBetaDistribution

  let alpha-value 5
  let beta-value 5
  let pdf []
  repeat 50000 [set pdf lput rngs:rnd-beta 1 alpha-value beta-value pdf]

  set-current-plot "beta distribution curve"
  histogram pdf

end
```

Note that you will need to create a plot in your interface called "beta distribution curve" for this to work